# OSB: Assign a value from $header to variable in error handler

Tags: variables, header, variable-assignment, assign, osb

Dear Stackoverflowers,

this is my first post, so I try to do everything correct.

In the error handler of an OSB component, I need to assign a value from the existing $originalHeader to another variable to reuse it, without entering the value as text.

In an assign-action, the expression `$originalHeader/privateMetaAttributesHeader/LoggingCategory`
for variable *originalLoggingCategory* does return the below:

[Debugging_VariablesScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGfMf.png)

I do not understand why the value of LoggingCategory is not assigned to variable *originalLoggingCategory*. Please help me out with this.

Content of $originalHeader:

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v1:privateMetaAttributesHeader xmlns:v1="http://www.example.org/scintilla/meta/v1"><SwingMonitoring>...</SwingMonitoring><LoggingCategory>com.schenker.scintilla.AirOcean.WWTAN.LoadPlanInstructionService.v1</LoggingCategory></v1:privateMetaAttributesHeader></soapenv:Header>
```

Thanks in advance.
Patrick

Comment: Do you have any luck with Assign xpath being $originalHeader//LoggingCategory?   The root element of XML is synonymous with your variable name ... so $originalHeader = privateMetaAttributesHeader.    (... which also means in your Request you had done ASSIGN $originalHeader=$header/privateMetaAttributesHeader.)

Comment: Also, your screenshot does not match what you pasted as $originalHeader

Comment: @Jonathan, yes, I assigned the $header into $originalHeader as it would be overwritten somewhere in between. I was able to solve it using the correct / defined namespace 'v1' at the appropriate element 'privateMetaAttributesHeader'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `<privateMetaAttributesHeader>` and `<v1:privateMetaAttributesHeader>`, which OSB rightly respects.

for instance

- `$originalHeader/privateMetaAttributesHeader/LoggingCategory` may be null
- `$originalHeader/v1:privateMetaAttributesHeader/v1:LoggingCategory` will probably return what you want (try selecting just the header at first, then work your way down to the logging category, just in case LoggingCategory isn't in the v1 namespace)

You can define what namespace 'v1' is in the OSB Proxy Stage, or if you don't know, you can use `$originalHeader/*:privateMetaAttributesHeader/*:LoggingCategory` but that's not recommended.

Comment: Hi Trent, thank you so much for the help! I already had the idea, but I didn't know that the namespace I was referring to was unknown. So I defined a new one with URL in the namespace definitions tab.

`$originalHeader/v1:privateMetaAttributesHeader/LoggingCategory/text()`

worked out!